# Why does form submit with preventDefault?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop over all the fields in this form. I've collected all the form fields in an array and I have a `forEach` to loop over them, but I'm stuck on the `preventDefault()` not working.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("fakeForm");

Array.from(form.elements).forEach((element, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (element == "") {
    alert("Please complete all fields!");
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="fakeForm" id="fakeForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="last name">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify more your purpose?

Comment: The goal is to submit the form, but only after all fields are complete. If any of the fields are empty, do not submit the form.

Comment: It should be done using validation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preventDefault` is a property of `event`. You are trying to call it on an index of an array called `e` in this example.

Usually you wait for `submit` event and then call `preventDefault`:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

Edit:

If you want to check if every field is valid, you should use validation.

But if you don't want to do this for some reason...

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
  const isFormFilled = Array.from(form.elements).every((element) => {
    return element !== ''
  });

  if (!isFormFilled) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

Comment: How would that work with the array and `forEach` I have going?

Comment: Checking if every field is empty, and if not... then submit... Isn't that validation?

Comment: It's not [accessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility) so I don't consider it a real thing